# How to combine in the icon or avatar function of the model list in datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, datagridview, icons, datagridviewcolumn

How to combine in the icon or avatar function of the model list IN datagridview in VB.NET.

The code function below only takes the value from the codeproduct so that each row of the DataGridView changes its color. Can the code function combine with a "barcode"? .

Thanks

```
  Public Class Item
        Public Property Id() As Integer
        Public Property CodeProduct() As String
        Public Property Barcode() As String
        Public Function GetAvatar() As DataGridViewAvatar
            Return New DataGridViewAvatar() With {
            .Value = CType(Me.CodeProduct, String),
            .Icon = Image.FromFile("money.png")
        }
        End Function
    End Class
```